# General Convolution Formula for Functions

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, with probability density functions (pdfs) $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

Suppose we have a new random variable as the sum of these two variables $Z = X + Y$,

The convolution of $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ is defined as:

$$f_Z(z) = (f_X * f_Y)(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) dx$$

**My Question:**  Suppose we have many random variables $x_1$ , $x_2$....$x_n$ with probability distributions $f(x_1)$, $f(x_2), ...$f(x_n)$.

**Is there some general formula for the convolution of some arbitrary function** $g(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ ?

For example, can we find out the probability distribution of some arbitrary function   $g(x1,x2,…,xn)$ = ($x_1$ + $x_2$) / $x_n$ ?

I have seen such a formula for additions of probability distributions, but for nothing more than this.

Thanks!

Comment: That convolution formula only holds if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The general convolution formula (which also only holds if the variables are independent) is the integral of $f_1(x_1) \dots f_n(x_n)$ over the region $x_1 + \dots + x_n = z$.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan: thank you for your reply! Could you please write an answer if you have time? Thank you so much!